Can I use wildcard in Route53 DNS SVR record
I have a requirement to add same ipaddress to all the following SVR record.
_sip._udp.foo.example.com
_sip._udp.bar.example.com
_sip._udp.baz.example.com
So on.
Is it possible have one single record like flowing instead of three record
_sip._udp.*.example.com
I have read in documentation that * acts as wildcard if added at start of domain name like *.example.com. But for SVR record what is start of record? (Proto and Transport excluded)
